# Só o último item do array é exibido

Tags: php, comentários

Como reproduzir um código em php, estilo ao um sistema de comentários.

Utilizando este código eu consegui sim fazer com que isso fosse possível mas, do mesmo jeito o código retorna apenas o último item da consulta:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("charset: UTF-8");

$comment_id = $_GET["postID"];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw");
mysql_select_db("run");

$cmd = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `POST_ID` LIKE '$comment_id' LIMIT 0,10";
$cmd_q = mysql_query($cmd);

$xmlpath = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd_q)) {
    $xmlpath = "<div id='comment.usr'>" . $row["POST_NAME"] . "</div> disse <div id='comment.content'>" . $row["POST_COMMENT"] . "</div>";
}

?>

<div id="comments">
    <?php echo $xmlpath; ?>
</div>
```

OBS: Se eu uso `$xmlpath += ...` ele retorna um zero ( 0 )

Comment: `<div id="comments">
    <?php echo $xmlpath; ?>
</div>` esse trecho deve estar dentro do while.

Comment: ok vou tentar!  .

Comment: @rray funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @rray comente como resposta pala eu marcar como aceito!

Comment: Dependendo do CSS, poderia funcionar apenas utilizando `$xmlpath .= ""; ` dentro do while, pois ele concatenaria todos os comentários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque o trecho de código `<div id="comments"><?php echo $xmlpath; ?></div>` dentro do while assim será impresso todos os comentários e não somente o último.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd_q)) {
    $xmlpath = "<div id='comment.usr'>" . $row["POST_NAME"] . "</div> disse <div id='comment.content'>" . $row["POST_COMMENT"] . "</div>";
    echo '<div id="comments">'. $xmlpath .'</div>';
}
```

O operado mais igual(`+=`) só funciona para números, para concatenar strings utilize o ponto(`.`) ou (`.=`).